# Reverse timezone lookup. Given a time, find location(s)

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, timezone

I am making a silly webapp with simple JavaScript for finding where in the world the time is closest to a given time. Like, "where in the world is it 2 pm right now?" I want to show these locations on a map. Currently I am using [timezones with moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to find timezones where the time is a given value, but I have no idea how to find some specific locations within these timezones (like coordinates or similar). I don't need to show *all* locations, just some. If anyone have any ideas how this can be done, or other approaches I am very thankful.

Clarification: I either want to do a lookup of cities where the local time equals to a given time, or a lookup of cities within a given timezone.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're looking for.  What kind of output would you want to obtain?  You said "coordinated or similar", but that doesn't make sense.  There are an infinite number of "coordinates" within any geographical region.  The number becomes finite when you lock down the desired precision, but surely you don't expect an array of every possible lat/lon in the US Pacific time zone to come out, given an input like `America/Los_Angeles`.  Maybe you are just looking for a shapefile?  Please elaborate.

Comment: https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder might be what you  are looking for.  Hard to say.